# In Redis mode, the data sent is different from the received data

Tags: ignite

In Redis mode, the sent data is different from the received data. The same problem with memcached. Here is an example of the code for Redis:

```
import pickle    
import redis

REDIS = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 6379,
    'db': 0
}

IGNITE = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 11211,
    'db': 0
}

def test_connection(redis_connection):
    d = {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 'AS213dfdsfфывфывфывфа',
        'c': None,
    }
    pickle_dumps = pickle.dumps(d)
    print(pickle_dumps)
    redis_connection.set('foo', pickle_dumps)
    print(redis_connection.get('foo'))
    print('-----------------------')


test_connection(redis.StrictRedis(**IGNITE))
test_connection(redis.StrictRedis(**REDIS))
```

That's how I run the Ignite:

```
docker run -p 11211:11211 -it -e "CONFIG_URI=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/ignite/master/examples/config/redis/example-redis.xml" apacheignite/ignite
```

Output:

```
b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X \x00\x00\x00AS213dfdsf\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd0\xb0q\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04Nu.'
b'\xef\xbf\xbd\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X \x00\x00\x00AS213dfdsf\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd0\xb0q\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04Nu.'
-----------------------
b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X \x00\x00\x00AS213dfdsf\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd0\xb0q\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04Nu.'
b'\x80\x03}q\x00(X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x01K\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x02X \x00\x00\x00AS213dfdsf\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb2\xd1\x84\xd0\xb0q\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00cq\x04Nu.'
-----------------------
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I can see that \x80 is replaced by \xef\xbf\xbd.

The latter is [Unicode representation of Replacement character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159118/incorrect-string-value-xef-xbf-xbd-for-column)

I expect this is the result of writing \x80 (a control character) into Unicode stream inside Ignite. I could find [a question about Pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17303266/how-to-pickle-unicodes-and-save-them-in-utf-8-databases) with a similar problem.

It also advices against using Pickle in network environment. Why don't you use e.g. JSON?