# How can I fix pickling Arabic text problem?

Tags: python, pickle

I am getting the problem while trying to pickle Arabic text to store it in a variable.
This is code:

```
# load the  train data & store it..
with open('files/0007.txt', 'rb') as f:
    train_data = pickle.load(f)
```

Error:

```
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fa360e8454ee> in <module>
      1 # load the  train data & store it in a file
      2 with open('files/0007.txt','rb') as f:
----> 3     train_data=pickle.load(f)

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xd8'.
```

Comment: what do you mean by `pickle arabic text ` ?

Comment: Was the pickle file created by the same version of python you are using to load the pickle file?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17307606/3358570

Comment: Also, it seems odd that a pickle file has a .txt extension. Most people use .pkl for pickle files

Comment: why is it `.txt` should not it be `.pkl`?

Comment: "what do you mean by pickle arabic text"                                                                                           i mean: when i use same code with english text/corpus it works, but not works with arabic text/corpus

Comment: here i use this code with texts in english, and it works:with open('files/train_qa.txt','rb') as f:
    train_data=pickle.load(f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Reason : file is corrupted
```

Try compressing the file, upload it and then unzip on the session. It looks like the pickle file is not saved correctly when you upload/downloaded it.